# R : Combining dataframes of unequal length

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

I have 16 dataframes of unequal lengths. I want to combine them into a single dataframe such that the resulting dataframe has the length of the longest of the 16 dataframes and fill all the empty cells with na value.
Can someone tell me how to do this in R? I am a novice in R so I have no idea ho to do this.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and show what you have already attempted. In general the dplyr package is well suited for data manipulation.
Usally functions such as `full_join` come in handy

Comment: @Joyvalley i used inner_join and it worked !

Comment: glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind_fill` function from `plyr` package for this. Check the below example:

```
> mydata<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c("a","b","c"))
> mydata2 <- data.frame(y1=c(4,5,6),y2=c("d","e","f"), y3=c(3323,544,6556))
> mydata
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
> mydata2
  y1 y2   y3
1  4  d 3323
2  5  e  544
3  6  f 6556
> plyr::rbind.fill(mydata,mydata2)
  x1   x2 y1   y2   y3
1  1    a NA <NA>   NA
2  2    b NA <NA>   NA
3  3    c NA <NA>   NA
4 NA <NA>  4    d 3323
5 NA <NA>  5    e  544
6 NA <NA>  6    f 6556
```

Let me know if this solves your purpose.